# Libreoffice takes too long to start in ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: libreoffice

Fresh install Ubuntu 20.04.1, Dell i3, 8 GB RAM, LibreOffice 6.4.6.2
It takes almost 4 minutes to start LibreOffice for first time,once it start it runs properly, after closing LibreOffice next time it starts with in 5 seconds. This happens every time after shutdown or restart, but always for first time, it's lighting fast once closed and restarted office.
For first start
time libreoffice --impress

(soffice:6850): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 22:49:14.565: gtk_widget_queue_draw_area: assertion 'height >= 0' failed
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

(soffice:6850): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 22:49:39.985: gtk_widget_queue_draw_area: assertion 'height >= 0' failed

(soffice:6850): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 22:49:44.643: gtk_widget_queue_draw_area: assertion 'height >= 0' failed

real    4m40.259s
user    0m8.866s
sys 0m1.661s
For second start
time libreoffice --impress

(soffice:28081): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 22:54:23.336: gtk_widget_queue_draw_area: assertion 'height >= 0' failed
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

(soffice:28081): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 22:54:26.317: gtk_widget_queue_draw_area: assertion 'height >= 0' failed

(soffice:28081): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 22:54:26.570: gtk_widget_queue_draw_area: assertion 'height >= 0' failed

real    0m10.562s
user    0m7.222s
sys 0m0.513s

Comment: That is extremely long. 1) You certainly have a traditional hard drive, and not a much faster SSD (add the system information to you post), but even then, 4 minutes is extreme. How long does it take booting your system? 2) If you have the snap version installed, move to the regular .deb version instead. snap versions tend to have a longer startup time. Also add the information about how LO is installed to your post. The version you mention does  not match current versions in snap and DEB.

Comment: @vanadium 6.4.6.2 is the current stable deb version of LO

Comment: You could look up the path to the LO executable when it's running by using `ps -ef | grep office` (the executable is `/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin` on my system) , end the program and start it up next time with `strace /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin` to see what it's doing for four minutes.

Comment: @User24601 for me it is still 6.4.5, both in APT and in snap (6.4.5.2) but indeed, might soon be updated for me as well. Still, OP best explicitly indicates his state.

Comment: Yes I do have traditional hard drive, but problems was not with ubuntu 18.04, booting takes 60-90 seconds, I had install regular .deb version install